# Несколько параметров натройки

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть несколько параметров настройки скроллера на jquery, например что-бы отражало 4 элемента:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        visible: 4
    });
});
</script>
```

Он работает, но если добавить еще один элемент в настройку то все крашится.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        wrap: 'circular'
        visible: 4
    });
});

</script>
```

Как правильно совместить параметры настройки?

Answer (score 2):

поставить запятую?

```
jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
    wrap: 'circular',
    visible: 4
});
```

Comment: Совсем забыл, спасибо)

Comment: @HappyCougar правильный ответ надо принять (галка слева от ответа)

Answer (score 0):

Не хватает запятой после `'circular'`